# JPA Hibernate - Set value of a specific column as null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have column in one of my Entity like below:

```
@Column(name = "lockedby",nullable = true)
private String lockedby;
```

And I have this in the Repository:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE MyEntity ac set ac.lockedby = ?1 where ac.myentityuuid = ?2")
void unlockMyEntity(String useremailid, String myentityuuid);
```

And from my Service I am trying to do this:

```
myEntityRepository.unlockMyEntity(null, myEntityObject.getMyentityuuid());
```

> **I am getting NO exceptions and NO messages/warnings WHATSOEVER.** And the value remains as is. Doesnt get nullified.

Whats going on here? Am I missing something here?

**Update:**

Situation seems even worse. Not just `null`, I cant update this entity with any other String value too. But yeah, my priority/requirement is to set the value as - `null` as stated in original question.

Comment: I think it's the placeholders.
Usually the best practice in parameterized queries is:  

    UPDATE MyEntity ac set ac.lockedby = :useremailid where ac.myentityuuid = :myentityuuid

Comment: Tried it before and now too... still the same thing Pam. Thanks for your help though.!

Comment: Sure, glad to help.  Following your update, seems like the wrong connection to the db, if nothing gets updated.  (how is the db configuration?  see which url you're working with...) OR, I would check the "commit" status... maybe the transaction is not closed, if there is any.

Comment: Not sure whats happening @PamStums but, putting `myEntityRepository.unlockMyEntity(null, myEntityObject.getMyentityuuid());` in a GET request worked perfectly as expected. It never worked in a POST method. Weird and Odd. !

Comment: GET and POST, well they're might be encoded differently, especially the null.  you could post the whole relevant code if you wish, would be easier in this way.

Comment: Try in this format: `@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.status = :status where u.name = :name")
int updateUserSetStatusForName(@Param("status") Integer status, 
  @Param("name") String name);`